# How to anchor TableView with Column?

Tags: qt, qml

I have a Column and a TableView. I want the TableView to be positioned under the Column so I tried this:

```
Window {
    id: root

//...

    Column{
        id: displayColumn

//...
        }
    }

    TableView {
        anchors.top: displayColumn.bottom
        clip: true
//....
        }
    }
}
```

But Tableview does not get displayed. Only the Columns are displayed.
I tried it with showing just TableView without the columns and that works.

Comment: Please provide [mcve] if you really want to get an answer. Please clarify what does "not work" mean?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is providing `width` and `height` for `Column`

```
Window {
    id: root

//...

    Column{
        id: displayColumn
        width: 30
        height: 30

//...
        }
    }

    TableView {
        anchors.top: displayColumn.bottom
        clip: true
//....
        }
    }
}
```